# Omission of Helping verb/auxiliary, When it is allowed?

Tags: sentence-construction

The convicts in this case remain unpunished till date, with their sentences doing the rounds in government offices

Is above sentence construction is correct?

Mainly use of remain unpunished till date. or it should be

a) case is/was remained unpunished till date,

b) case is/was remain unpunished till date,

Comment: @user105719 this should be an answer to the question.

Comment: convicts are people. Surely, you mean the convictions.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, *remain* functions as a linking verb. Linking verbs are often followed by adjectives or nouns and describe the subject.

> **[remain](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/remain)** *linking verb* to continue to be something; to be still in the same state or condition
>
> *The economy remains fragile.*
>   *Despite threats of strike action, the management remain hopeful that an agreement can be reached.*
>   *In spite of their quarrel, they remain the best of friends.*

From *[Practical English Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_English_Usage)*, Unit 11:

> Some verbs are used to join an adjective or noun complement to a subject. These verbs can be called 'linking verbs', 'copulas’ or 'copular verbs’. Common examples: *be*, *seem*, *appear*, *look*, *sound*, *smell*, *taste*, *feel*, *become*, *get*.
>
> *The weather is horrible.
>
>   She became a racehorse trainer.
>
>   I do feel a fool.
>
>   The stew smells good.
>
>   That car looks fast.
>
>   It's getting late.*